# CSV output for Number data

Tags: shell-script

Below is the .csv file and sample content it has tab delimiter. but when I open this file with notepad its look good for number. but if i open with excel, number data is not looking correct it looks +11 at the end but inside if I double click data is correct.

I want to see actual values instead of +11 at the end, if I open with excel sheet.
But, I dont want to do manually format the cells to text and see the value (or) format to number and see the data. that will be manual approach but I want this should be automated If file is generated file.csv from Informatica powercenter and open with excel and look the correct number without double click for that cell.

is this can be done with unix script? It is okay if it is possible with xlsx format instead of csv if it is not works with csv.

```
Name    Number      address      pin
John    23435435    usa          235
Jacob   2342342     india        234
Jack    35345345    uk           345
Jet     3234234     canada       323
jub     234234      australia    366
```

Comment: "it looks +11 at the end" ... what does this mean? Do you need to widen your columns? When you say "but inside if I double click data is correct", that implies the data is correct but either the columns are too narrow or the format has been improperly guessed. A screenshot would help here.